# GKE error "code=400, message=IP aliases cannot be used with a legacy network."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Simple computational cluster, hundred nodes, after update SDK to 253.0 getting error with previously working scripts

> gcloud container clusters create gnt --project=XXX  --machine-type n1-highcpu-2 --zone us-central1-f --num-nodes 50 --disk-size=30

Getting back "ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=IP aliases cannot be used with a legacy network."

Never asked for IP aliases, legacy network used to be good, so how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the flag `--no-enable-ip-alias` to your gcloud command for not using IP alias in your cluster.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I figured it out myself after posting the question, but this limit my cluster size (not critical for now, but might matter in the future). Also, as far as I can see, there is new way of doing things with ip aliasing enabled, so if you know how to do it, please tell me. Bumped the answer.

Comment: Creating a GKE cluster with the gcloud command by default will enable the VPC Native feature (IP aliases). VPC-native clusters use two secondary IP address ranges, one for the pods and the other for the services. I recommend you to check the [VPC-native guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) to see the benefits and the quick start guide.